# Can't start QT .exe file on Windows 7

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm getting started with Qt and have encountered the following issue: when i compile and run my application from within QtCreator it runs all right, but when i go to the debug folder and double click .exe file to launch the app a message box pops up and it says

> This application has failed to start because QtDeclaratived4.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem

Please notice - it is QtDeclaratived4.dll with letter d before 4, not QtDeclarative4.dll.

After searching in Google i found an advice to find the needed dll and put it inside project folder. But unfortunately such .dll is missing on my computer. I found QtDeclarative4.dll and tried putting it inside project folder but it didn't help.  Can you propose me any other solution?

Comment: The DLL referred to is the debug version of the QtDeclarative DLL. I don't develop with Qt Creator (I use Qt in Visual Studio) but I'm fairly certain you should have the DLL (otherwise your application should not run in debug mode from within Qt Creator either). If you don't you can always build it.

Comment: you mean i can build .dll file? can you explain me how to do that or give me a link?

Comment: First verify that you really don't have that DLL. I'm pretty certain you must have it.

Comment: searching in my computer can't find it whereas QtDeclarative4.dll is found instantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **`d`** in the name indicates the **debug** version of Qt, which means that you compiled your application using the [debug build](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.4/creator-build-settings.html).

You probably have this DLL on your computer and Qt Creator knows where it is, that's why it is able to run your application. **However**, you don't have the path to this library configured in your **`PATH`** environment variable, that's you are not able to executable your application manually (i.e. outside Qt Creator).

To fix this issue, you have 2 choices:

- Compile your application selecting the release build;
- Or add the full path to `QtDeclaratived4.dll` to the `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

`QtDeclarative4.dll` can be found in `C:\[QT_INSTALL_DIR]\bin`

You should definitely have this if you used the standard Windows installer that Qt distrubutes.